# How do i Center this Simple Slideshow?

Tags: css, slideshow

I have been trying to get this slideshow to center without success:

http://www.lateralcode.com/simple-slideshow/

It seems the `position: absolute` is what is really messing with me...

How do I center this slideshow so that upon page resize it looks correct, and the slideshow still works correctly?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this:

```
.ppt img { margin-left:-50%; }
.ppt li { left:50%; }
```

Comment: obviously leave the other css rules, including `position:absolute` on the `.ppt li`

Comment: Ah. Thanks, i had to use: .ppt img { margin-left:-50%; } and .ppt li { left:50%; } for it to work.

Comment: that's interesting.  That's what I originally tried in Chrome and what usually works for me, but it didn't work until I made it -100% yesterday - not sure why.  Please accept this as the answer by hitting the check mark if this is what worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can center elements which got css property `position:absolute` like this:

```
.elem { 
    position: absolute; width:200px; height:200px; left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; /* you need to deduct half width from margin left */
}
```

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/jMBaV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

wrap that ul with div .

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul></ul>
</div>

#slider{
width:650px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto"
}
```